# HTML export: How to link back to main page from subpages?

Tags: export, html

When exporting to [HTML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html), there is an option to create separate pages for closed cell groups. This is done with the `"ConvertClosed" -> "LinkedPage"` option, or with the following setting in the Save As... HTML options:

[image]

**How can I get Mathematica to include a link back to the main page from the subpage corresponding to the cell group?**

When there are nested closed cell groups, each subpage should link back to the page above it in the hierarchy (which is not necessarily the top level page).

---

#### Example

If we start with this notebook, *and close Section One* ...

[image]

... then we get these two pages. The first one links to the second, but the second one does not link to the first.

[image]